# Do there exist two vectors in a Hilbert space such that $(x,y)\geqslant k\|x-y\|^{-2}$?

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(x,y)$ denote the inner product of the elements $x,y\in H$, $\|x\|$ denote the norm of $x\in H$, and $k>0$.

Do there exist such $x,y\in H$ that
$$
(x,y)\geqslant\frac{k}{\|x-y\|^{2}} ?
$$

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes. You can take any $x,y$ with positive inner product and multiply them by some large number. Since you are new to the site, I'll suggest to (a) provide some context for your questions; (b) use words, not only formulas, in the title. See [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/147263)

Answer (score 1):

Take $e_1,e_2$ to be the orthonormal basis of $\mathrm{span}<x,y>$ and without loss of generality take $x\in \mathrm{span}<e_1>$. Now we can write the coordinates: $x=ae_1$ and $y=be_1+ce_2$ and evaluate $(x,y)=ab$ and $\|x-y\|^2=(x,x)+(y,y)-2(x,y)=a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab$. If we now rewrite the inequality:
$(x,y)\|x-y\|^2\geq k$ and we substitute:
$$ab(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab)\geq k$$
we then do some movement and obtain:
$$c^2\geq \frac{k+2(ab)^2}{ab}-(a^2+b^2)$$
Which clearly have infinite solutions. When we fix some $a$ and $b$ real we see that we get our lower bound for a positive $c$.